# Error: couldn't find dependency [gazebo_msgs] of [pr2_tabletop_manipulation_gazebo_demo]

Tags: ros, cturtle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I tried to get the PR2 Pick and Place Demo working. In the compiling part after running "rosmake pr2_tabletop_manipulation_gazebo_demo" I got this out put:

```
root@reza2-laptop:~/Downloads# rosmake pr2_tabletop_manipulation_gazebo_demo
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['pr2_tabletop_manipulation_gazebo_demo']                                                                                
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/reza2/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130301-154404                                                                      
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['pr2_tabletop_manipulation_gazebo_demo'] to:
['pr2_tabletop_manipulation_gazebo_demo']                                            
[ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages pr2_tabletop_manipulation_gazebo_demo.  This may take a few seconds.                                    
Failed to find stack for package [rosgraph_msgs]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [rosgraph_msgs]:Cannot locate installation of package rosgraph_msgs: [rospack] couldn't find package [rosgraph_msgs]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/cturtle/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/reza2/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_overlay/model_database:/home/reza2/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_overlay/wg_robots_gazebo:/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks:/opt/ros/cturtle/ros]
Failed to find stack for package [gazebo_msgs]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [gazebo_msgs]:Cannot locate installation of package gazebo_msgs: [rospack] couldn't find package [gazebo_msgs]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/cturtle/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/reza2/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_overlay/model_database:/home/reza2/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_overlay/wg_robots_gazebo:/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks:/opt/ros/cturtle/ros]
[rosstack] couldn't find dependency [bullet] of [wg_robots_gazebo]
[rosstack] missing dependency
[ rosmake ] rosdep check passed all system dependencies in packages                                                                                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pr2_tabletop_manipulation_gazebo_demo [ make ]                                                                                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
 No Makefile in package roslang                                                              
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                                                                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib                                                                                                
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                                                                                                   
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp                                                                                            
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                                                                                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole                                                                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                                                                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp                                                                                                
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]                                                                                                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout                                                                                                
[ rosmake ] All 22 linesr2_tabletop_manipulation_gazebo_demo: 0.1 sec ]                                                             [ 1 Active 8/9 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package pr2_tabletop_manipulation_gazebo_demo
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/cturtle/ros/bin/rospack deps-manifests pr2_tabletop_manipulation_gazebo_demo
  [rospack] couldn't find dependency [gazebo_msgs] of [pr2_tabletop_manipulation_gazebo_demo]
  [rospack] missing dependency
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/cturtle/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:113 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
    'pr2_tabletop_manipulation_gazebo_demo'.  Look above for errors from
    rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the broken dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/cturtle/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:183 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package pr2_tabletop_manipulation_gazebo_demo written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/reza2/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130301-154404/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_gazebo_demo/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pr2_tabletop_manipulation_gazebo_demo [FAIL] [ 0.19 seconds ]                                                                       
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package pr2_tabletop_manipulation_gazebo_demo. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                     
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                                         
[ rosmake ] Built 9 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                                                
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                                      
[ rosmake ] /home/reza2/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130301-154404
```

I have Cturtle installed on Ubuntu 10.04 and already installed arm-navigation for using ompl by:

```
 sudo apt-get install ros-cturtle-arm-navigation
```

I have for example gazebo_msgs but it is under fuerte installation. So is there is any general package missing in my cturtle here or shall I get those missing dependencies one by one? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56729/error:-couldn%27t-find-dependency-%5Bgazebo_msgs%5D-of-%5Bpr2_tabletop_manipulation_gazebo_demo%5D/) by [Reza Ch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1696/reza-ch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2013-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Crossing cturtle and fuerte is likely going to get you into trouble.  It looks like you're missing gazebo_msgs from your environment.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0